# Reputation points in careers differs from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, jobs

[In my careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jbruni), it shows `634` reputation points. If you look at my account on Stack Overflow, it shows that I have `704` reputation points.

However, when I browse to my `reputation` recalculation screen (will be different for you), it shows `696` points.

What is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the report J. Bruni.

MY FAULT on the careers stuff. We were having some stability issues with the server that was running the careers reputation update process a week or so ago so we moved them a more stable server.

What we failed to do was move over our service monitors that tell me when things have problems and, well, things had problems (of course!). Everything is back up and running, so your stats on careers will update soon (by the end of the day, we have to go through everyone in the db).

**UPDATE** : Everything's all better now.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Now, my reputation points are the same everywhere. :-) Unfortunately, I've "lost" a few of them... instead of 704, the correct value seems to be 696. I think I should earn the missing 8 points for this report! :-) *just kidding* ... thx

Comment: @J. Bruni: No problem, sir.

Answer (score 5):

Your recalc screen is an 'up to the minute' update of what your reputation score is.  When you click on the link, splines are reticulated, scores are recalculated, and poof.

In fact, if you click on that `trigger recalc` button, I'd wager that your profile score would start to match that score.

As far as your careers score, I don't have an answer to that except to guess that it is either de-normalized (and would be updated after a recalc, since hopefully that updates other tables?) or the reputation fairy just hasn't gotten to that service yet.  I'm guessing the former, though with the abudance of unicorns present in the datacenter, fairies are not out of the question either.

Comment: Flair itself is 24 hours delayed, which I would suspect is the reason for the discrepency.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I clicked the "trigger recalc" button before asking this question... I should have mentioned it.